# What is the usage of contenteditable and can I use it in as edit profile button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the usage of contenteditable in html5 and how I save the changes in contenteditable div in mongoose/MongoDB and show these updated details to the users?

```
<h2>Edit your profile username:</h2>

<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
   bisc452
</div>

<button>Save Changes</button>
```

I expect it can be done without javascript so with the user disable javascript he can save changes but if it needs to be with javascript or jquery it good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking just plain text from users like profile username then there is no need for contenteditable. You can just use the `<input >` tag for this.

HTML -

```html
<form >
    Edit your profile username: 
    <input type="text" name="username" id="profileUsername" value="username">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('profileUsername').value)">Save Changes</button>
```

javascript -

```
function myFunction(profileUserName) {
  console.log("Profile username : "+ profileUserName);
  // Save this value in MongoDB here
}
```

Contenteditable is generally used for editors like the one used by StackOverflow to write a question and answer where the input by users is not only text but text with some formatting. If you want to use contenteditable for any reason then -

```html
<h2>Edit your profile username:</h2>

<div id="myText" contenteditable="true">
   bisc452
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML)">Save Changes</button
```

javascript -

```
function myFunction(profileUserName) {
  console.log("Profile username : "+ profileUserName);
  // Save this value in MongoDB here
}
```

Comment: You can put `document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML` inside the function itself, using a `const` if necessary.